# How do I force refetch a relationship set of a NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, core-data

How do I force-refetch a relationship of a nsmanagedobject from Persistent store?

The relationship is an nsset. Its content could have been changed by other contexts. Changes may include new elements in the set, deletions and updations of existing elements in the set.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different NSManagedObjectContexts you need to listen for the "save".

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateStuff:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Once it's done then you can "refresh" your data.

```
- (void)updateStuff:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSArray *array = [myEntity.theRelationship allObjects];
}
```